# Spring-Boot JPA - Inserting into Two Table Relation Inheritance with single forms in angular

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm attempting to save records to a database two table that includes a foreign key using Spring-Boot and angular but I don't know how to figure it :

by the way this is my entities classes with relation inheritance :

[Entitie User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Mip.png)

[Entitie Patient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9KZN.png)

And For consuming data API I use this post method for register :

[Register Post Controller Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhvhH.png)

In Angular Projet I have Put This Register Method on services for user :

> ```
>   const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/';
>   register(user: User): Observable<any> {
>     return this.http.post(API_URL + 'registration', JSON.stringify(user),
>   {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}});
>   }
> ```

And For Register Component I Use this :

> ```
> register() {
> this.userService.register(this.user).subscribe(data => {
>   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
> }, err => {
>   this.errorMessage = 'Username is already exist.';
> });   }
> ```

so in this case I want when it files all form input and click on insert it will insert data for both table user and patient at the same.

**any help can be appreciated thank uu**

Comment: you shouldn't JSON.stringify the passed data. angular will do it for you. I don't see what is the problem in your question

Comment: the problem is how to register data for both table patient and user it just insert into user not patient

Comment: If I get it right, this logic should be on the backend side